# IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed: - in validating form missing user id (foreing key of anothermodel)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, super, misaka

**Previous title: Unable to import 'misaka' - Django**

I am following a tutorial about how to build a social network.

I run into this error:

> IntegrityError at /posts/new/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
> posts_post.user_id

Complete traceback (please note the lines in bold):

```
The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py in dispatch
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py in post
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py in post
            return self.form_valid(form) …


▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Tommaso\Django rest framework\Udemy Django\simplesocial\posts\views.py in form_valid
        **return super().form_valid(form)** …


▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py in form_valid
        self.object = form.save() …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in save
            self.instance.save() …


▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Tommaso\Django rest framework\Udemy Django\simplesocial\posts\models.py in save
        **super().save(*args, **kwargs)** …


▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in save_base
                force_update, using, update_fields, …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _save_table
            result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _do_insert
                               using=using, raw=raw) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in manager_method
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in execute_sql
                cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in execute
            return super().execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py in __exit__
                raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) …
▶ Local vars
```

The lines in bold are pointing to these two pieces of code:

1: In my_project\posts\views.py in form_valid:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form) #<--highligted line
```

2: In my_project\posts\models.py in save

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.message_html = m.html(self.message)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs) #<--highligted line
```

These functions are run when a user posts a new post inside a group of the social network.

I am using VScode, so I noticed that apparently, my code does not recognise [misaka](https://misaka.61924.nl/), installed via pip and imported as follows:

```
import misaka as m
```

> Pylint import error: Unable to import 'misaka'

I have read misaka documentation but I can't understand what is wrong. 
please note I am using Misaka v. 2.1.0, that apparently does not need to be installed in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.

Any thoughts?

Since it has been suggested that I am  trying to create a Post model object into the database without setting the user foreign key, here you can see my my_project/posts/model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse #vho corretto io, ersione di django cambiata
from django.conf import settings

import misaka as m

from groups.models import Group

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="posts", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = m.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username':self.user.username, 'pk':self.pk})

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created_at']
            unique_together = ['user', 'message']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to insert a Post model object into the database without setting the User foreign key.

You should set it to the user object attached to the request first.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Check [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

Comment: Isn't line **self.object = self.request.user** already doing it? (my_project\posts\views.py in form_valid)

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

As suggested by @ebram-shehata, the code was trying to insert a Post model object into the database without setting the User foreign key, and this is because in the `form_valid(self, form)` method I mispelled a line.

I substituted

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

with:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

add :

```
self.object.user = self.request.user
```

And replace `self.object` with `self.object()`

So that you obtain:

```
def form_valid(self, form): 
    self.object = form.save(commit=False) 
    self.object.user = self.request.user 
    self.object.save() 
    return super().form_valid(form)
```